# How to read in a file but skip characters after #?

Tags: c, scanf

Have a problem to read in a file in c. Have been searching online since I'm a beginner in programming but still I have a problem with the output of my file.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *in;
    int chr;

    if(in = fopen("airmap1.map", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        exit(1);

    while(fgets(row, sizeof(row),in) !=NULL){
            if (*row == '#') //next row
            continue;
            fscanf(in, "%*[^\n]s , %[]s", row); 
    }
}
```

The file I want to read in is looking like this:

```
#animals at the zoo
cat dog #cat-dog
fish frog #fish-frog
```

I want to ignore comments after this sign #, but my problem is that my code only ignore the first word after #.  But right now it gives me this output:

```
cat frog 
dog fish
```

How can i solve this problem? I would like to have the output this form instead:

```
cat dog
fish frog
```

Comment: ".. only ignore the first word after #" is a wrong description of what *actually* happens. `*row == '#'` only *checks* the first character (it kind of depends on the definition of `row`, which is left out of your example (because it seems unimportant?)). You need to re-think your strategy -- `#` can occur *anywhere*.

Comment: Code sample does not compile.

Comment: `row` is not declared, `if(in = fopen("airmap1.map", "r")) == NULL)` is a wrong code

Comment: This format `"%*[^\n]s , %[]s"` matches none of the file you showed. And mixing `fgets` and `fscanf` is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: Hint: read the file one line at a time using `fgets`. On that line, search for the first `#` character with `strchr`. If one is found, replace it with a `'\n'` and replace the following one with a null character (`'\0'`). And write that line to stdout or split it in words.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function that checks for any "#" in every line of the file, and then copy it in another string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define commentSign '#'
#define bufferLength 255

int findPosOfChar(char * buffer, char charToFind, int length)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
  {
    if(buffer[i] == charToFind)
      return i;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE* filePointer = fopen("test", "r");
  char buffer[bufferLength];
  char *p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
  int commentPos;

  while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, filePointer)) {
      commentPos = findPosOfChar(buffer, (char)commentSign, bufferLength);
      memcpy(p, buffer, commentPos);
      p[commentPos] = '\0';

      printf("%s\n", p);
  }

  fclose(filePointer);
}
```

Comment: This will not work. imagine you have no "#" in your line, so your `commentPos` function will return **0** and you will not copy the line content !

Comment: I already tested it and it works. https://repl.it/repls/GrandioseRedPrinter

Comment: I test your program. it don't work as expected if you have a line **WITHOUT # character**, or if the character # is at position >255 of a line. Try to **REMOVE** '#' from line 1 of your test file, or make a line of 280 characters and put '#' at position 170. you will see ...